# why Typescript does not display error when using "each" inside foreach with annonymous function but throws correct error when using arrow function?

Tags: typescript, arrow-functions

In typescript I have following code which throws error and I know "each" is not valid and I have to use "forEach"

```
objTablesToCheck.forEach(objTable => {
   for (let i = aggregateStartIdx; i < numOfCells; i++) {
        //TypeScript thorws error at compile time and I know "each" is not valid and I have to use forEach 
        //getNthColumnCells return type is Array<HTMLTableCellElement>
        this.getNthColumnCells(objTable, colNum).each(objCell => {
             //my Logic
        }
    }
}
```

However, TypeScript does not throw error at compile time? Why is "each" Valid for this code block?

```
objTablesToCheck.forEach(objTable => {
   for (let i = aggregateStartIdx; i < numOfCells; i++) {
        //TypeScript does NOT throw error at compile time  
        //getNthColumnCells return type is Array<HTMLTableCellElement>
        this.getNthColumnCells(objTable, colNum).each(function(objCell) {
             //my Logic
        }
    }
}
```